# Is SSD speed related to its storage capacity?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I remember my teacher saying something about SSD and HDD speeds: 
suppose you want to read data at addresses X, Y and Z,
the mechanical drive has to walk through the sectors 3 times in order to retrieve the info. The electronic drive, in other hand, reads all data at once. Because of this the SSDs speed increases with its storage capacity.

But googling about it people say the bigger SSDs are faster just because they are made with better
components.

Maybe I misunderstood the explanation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying this a bit: SSDs rely on NAND - and the blocks on NAND have to be erased before they can be overwritten - but if they are already erased or unwritten, that time-consuming step isn't needed.

So erased NAND is faster than overwriting existing data on NAND, and SSD firmware does a lot of sleight-of-hand behind the scenes to try to write to erased parts of NAND before doing erase-then-write cycles which are slower.  Therefore, generally, a larger capacity drive is going to have more erased NAND available for new writes, so it will be able to work faster for longer.

I would say given the same SSD controller and firmware version, because of this, the speed will depend on the percent capacity of space that is used on the drive.

Larger drives will take longer to fill up so they can handle more writes before being forced to perform erases in order to overwrite existing data.

Of course there is TRIM which does allow the OS to tell the SSD that it can erase blocks and keep the drive fast.  Older SSDs without TRIM would certainly get slower the longer they are used (and a higher capacity would delay this) because the SSD is never erasing any NAND.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, partly. Most SSD controller chips have multiple channels they can utilize in parallel. Much like Dual Channel RAM, in fact. In some series, the smaller versions don’t have all channels connected. As such, they have lower performance.

And because of what ultrasawblade said, write performance benefits more from multi-channel access.

Comment: So writing to larger SSDs is faster because there will be more erased NAND gates and reading speed is faster because they have more potential to have multiple channels in parallel ?

Comment: Even when full (or non-TRIMed), the multiple channels will help keep performance at an acceptable level. Of course, the SSD will be even faster when it has lots of free space.

Comment: But supposing some SSD is small but has a lot of connected channels, it's reading speed will be faster than a larger SSD with fewer channels ?

Comment: No, even SSDs with fewer populated channels are still good enough to virtually saturate SATA III. Look at [this comparison](http://geizhals.de/?cmp=1122682&cmp=1122681&cmp=1122680), for example. It’s all about write speed.